# Runtime errors might occur when converting lambda expression to parameter type system.linq.expressions

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, lambda

I have the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<OrderLines> RetrieveOrderLines(Expression<Func<OrderLines,
                                                   bool>> expression)
{
    return _context.OrderLines.Where(expression);
}
```

This method is used from a test project (C#):

```
var testLine = repo.RetrieveOrderLines(x => x.I_ID == 1 
                                         && x.T_ID == 2).Single();
```

And our production project which is VB.Net also accesses this method like this:

```
Dim line As OrderLines = repo.RetrieveConsumptionLines(Function(x) x.I_ID = InvId 
                                                       And x.T_ID = tId).Single()
```

The C# test is working fine, I am not getting any error or warning,  but the line in VB is highlighted and re-sharper is giving me the following warning:

**runtime errors might occur when converting lambda expression to parameter 
type system.linq.expressions.expression(Of System.Func(Of OrderLines, Boolean))**

any idea why and is there are solution or a better way of doing this? I am new to Lambda expressions so any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that the verbatim message? I would have expected it to have a few google mentions (other than this question). But: does it *work*?

Comment: I have googled this but could not find anything useful.It works but I want to know why the warning?

Comment: Resharper tends to give you possible refactored solutions to use, can you see what it changes the code to.

Comment: it *sounds* like that is coming from resharper... however: what are `InvId` and `tId` here? local variables? fields? properties? what? I wonder if declaring local variables as snapshots of the (say) properties (and using the snapshots in the lambda) might help.